# How to test ETL pipelines

Tags: apache-spark, testing, databricks, integration-testing, etl

I'm building ETL pipelines with Azure Databricks and Spark and I'm wondering how to test them properly - namely during integration. I don't have any experience yet on what would be the right approach, so I'm interested in approaches from others.

This pipeline runs 4x a day, loading data into a SQL DB that is accessed by a web application.

There will certainly be unit tests to cover the transformation logic, but then we would also validate that the pipeline is running successfully and be aware if anything goes wrong.

Since the project is set up in AzureDevOps, we already have some test cases set up, including API tests and e2e browser tests. These tests are automatically run every day for the deployed application.
In addition, these test cases are formally executed by test managers before each release.
It is not currently mandatory to do the same for ETL pipelines, but we are currently investigating whether something like this would be useful for ETL as well.

I would imagine that in case of ETL pipelines we would need to set up a test database that is spun up and down after each test execution.
I'm just wondering if setting up such an integration test is worth the effort and cost, or if proper monitoring and unit testing will suffice.

We are currently in investigation phase. Current idea is to have unit tests + proper monitoring.
I am expecting exchange with others on testing strategies of ETL pipelines.